# Нужна помощь с Json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Есть несколько интересующих меня вопросов:

1. Если мы делаем свой json через PHP и к нашей json странице подключаются много сайтов что то типо rss. Дает ли нам это нагрузку на нашу mySql?
2. Как лучше всего хранить небольшое количество данных (допустим товары) для сайта у которого большая посещаемость?
3. Есть ли способ, который вы знаете что бы работать с БД на Js без node.js?

Comment: Вместо того, что бы минусовать задавайте наводящие вопросы. Парень не в теме.

Comment: Может стоит реализовать что-то вроде кеширования?

Comment: 1. Json - это фрормат данных. Как html или xml. 2. Зависит от структуры данных и сложности выборки. Если с умом подойти к вопросу, можно на самых медленных бд сделать достаточно быстрый сайт. 3 Как без node.js вообще запустить js и при чем тут PHP? Если у Вас несколько вопросов, не стоит все пихать в один.

Comment: Не забывайте отмечать ответ решающий ваш вопрос!

Answer (score 3):

1. Если я правильно понял, то вы реализуете API. У вас в базе хранятся какие-то данные, которые при запросе преобразуются в JSON и отдаются. То есть, формально, это ничем не отличается от обычной страницы. При каждом запросе скрипт будет лезть в базу и формировать нужные данные. Так что, да. Нагрузка на базу будет.
2. Самый простой совет - разбить данные по максимальному количеству признаков. Цена, количество, наличие и так далее. Чтобы свести постобработку данных к минимуму.
3. Если цель - работать с базой именно через JS, то без Node - это сложновато. А если язык не принципиален, то можно обойтись и без Node. Тот же PHP прекрасно работает с базой.

Comment: Или не использовать PHP. Совершенно не понятно, какие задачи решаются. Тут можно даже чистый си посоветовать :) Абстракция...

Comment: Ну если язык не принципиален, то да, можно выбрать хоть чистый Си)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, если я правильно понял, тебе нужно реализовать API сервис.

API сервис это такое web приложение которые в ответ на Http запрос возвращает не Html страничку а сырые данные в формате json.

Для создания api сервиса ты можешь использовать php он достаточно производительный и выдержит большие нагрузки, если всё правильно сделать и настроить.

можно обойтись и без node.js, под php можешь использовать другой web сервис который работает с php, apache например.

Comment: Изменил немного вопрос

Answer (score 0):

1. Нагрузка напрямую зависит от объема данных. Ее очень легко снизить используя инструменты серверного кеширования. Принцип такого кеширования заключается в том что когда сервер обрабатывает HTTP-запрос он берет данные не из базы данных, а из сохраненного json-файла. Предварительно проверяя срок годности кеша, если срок превышен то данные в кеше обновляются. Самым распространненым решением для кеширования на сегодня является [Memcached](https://memcached.org/)
2. Лучшим решением для вас будет использование MySQL, так как оно является достаточно масштабируемым, сегодня небольшое количество товаров, а завтра большое. А проблема с высокой посещаемостью решается при помощи кеширования. Кешировать данные можно на различных уровнях. Проще всего на уровне веб-сервера. К примеру на ngnix вы можете [настроить кеширование](https://habrahabr.ru/post/124684/) веб-страниц по url. И сайт залетает.
3. Исходя из всех заданных вопросов напрашивается вывод что вы делаете API для сайта, для ускорение процесса был разработана технология GraphQL, которая позволит вам не изобретая велосипеда быстро и гибко настроить JSON-api для вашего сервиса. Она имеет реализации на множестве языков в том числе есть [версия для PHP](http://graphql.org/code/#php) - это и есть ответ на ваш третий вопрос

Answer (score 0):

ставишь cron на запуск скрипта с какой-то периодичностью который рендерит JSON из mySql и сохраняет в файл. user's подключаются к файлу. Файл обновляется например раз в минуту. один call в минуту.